# How to perform transpose or establish "horizontal hierarchy" using python, excel, vba, power bi or power query?

Tags: python, excel, vba, powerbi, powerquery

I have a data set that look like this

[image]

It **shows** the **cost item within each division** for **each cost type and projects**.

There are many divisions and lots of cost items within each division. Adding all divisions give you the **total project cost for each project.**

**Problem!!!!**

**I want to show the break down of the division cost for each project.** Sth you can expand and collapse for each project.

But I can't establish a hierarchy in power bi as there is no column that reflects the relationship between each divisions and its cost items.

So i tried to transpose/alter the data set so it looks like this

[image]

[image]

**How do i do this with python/vba?

I think multiple looping in vba can solve this problem. **But are there any other approaches?**

Comment: you could bring the data into powerquery with data ... from table/range, click select first two columns, right click unpivot other columns, then file close and load it back to excel